# I can't fix a broken image in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, image, internet-explorer

I have a broken image in IE that I can't seem to fix.  I have tried everything I could think of so far. It works just fine in all browsers except IE.  You can view the broken image here...

http://74.53.164.152/~maury66/index.php?cPath=5_11

As you can see, all of the product images work except for the one for the product titled "Facial Hydrating Lotion - 120 ml/4 fl oz - For normal and oily skin types".

Does anyone have any idea what would be causing this? Any advice or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your JPEG code, you will see Photoshop data. You need to do **Save for web** instead of Save As.

Answer (score 4):

It's a [**CMYK**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK) image.

IE can't handle CMYK images.